# Find a Sequence of Real Numbers which Converge to $0$, but which is not in Any Space $\ell^p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find a Sequence $x = (x_1,x_2,...)$ of real numbers which converge to $0$, but which is not in any space $\ell^p(\mathbb{R}), 1 \leq p < \infty$.

So far I've come up with the (somewhat trivial) example $x_k = \frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{p}}}$. But I assume whoever wrote the problem would prefer a sequence independent of $p$.

Comment: What about the sequence 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, ... where each integer k appears as 1/k 2^k times ?

Comment: $1/\log n, n \ge 2$ would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the sequence $x_{n}=\frac{1}{\ln n}$ $(n>1)$meets the requirements. Obviously it converges to $0$. We just need to prove for any $1<p<+\infty$，there is $$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{{(\ln n)}^p}}=+\infty$$
It is easy to see that there is an positive integer N satisfies $\forall n>N$, $n^{\frac{1}{p}}>\ln n$. So $\forall n>N$, we have $\frac{1}{{(\ln n)}^p}>{\frac{1}{n}}$. According to $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}=+\infty$, we conclude $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{{(\ln n)}^p}}=+\infty$.